# Inserting data into partitioned table using bigquery does not insert data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to insert data using INSERT INTO DML command into partitioned BigQuery table from  a non-partitioned table .

Steps followed :

1.Creating empty partitioned table

CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.tbl1`
 ( field1 STRING, field2 STRING , field3 TIMESTAMP)
 PARTITION BY DATE(field3)
 OPTIONS(
   partition_expiration_days=3,
   description="a table partitioned "
 )

2.Inserting data from table2 to table1

INSERT INTO `dataset.tbl1`(field1, field2,field3) AS
select f1, f2,f3 from `project.dataset.tbl2` where 
DATE(f3) IN ('2018-09-13','2018-09-14','2018-09-15','2018-09-16') and f1 is not null and f2 is not null

The above DML statement gets executed but no records are inserted .So I check whether the SELECT query gets data or not.

The below fetches 13 records.

select f1, f2,f3 from `project.dataset.tbl2` where 
DATE(f3) IN ('2018-09-13','2018-09-14','2018-09-15','2018-09-16') and f1 is not null and f2 is not null

Comment: Can someone help on this asap

Comment: data usually shows up with a bit of delay, have you tried running the query again without cache

Comment: The problem got resolved when removed "partition_expiration_days"

Comment: Since it got resolved after removing "partition_expiration_days" - how long was this set up for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set partition_expiration_days=3, it means all partitions older than 3 days should expire and be deleted. You inserted data from 9/13 to 9/16, and since you posted yesterday I assume you ran the query on 9/26. So the data expired immediately after inserted to the table.

Comment: right , so the observation was if the partition date lies within partition_expiration_days=3 ,
ie if current_date is 2019-09-26 and partition_expiration_days is 3 so  date data that can be handled is 2018-09-24, 2018-09-25 and not  2018-09-23/2018-09-22 in partitions.