# How to Insert a partition into BigQuery's fetch time partitioned table in Python by specifying a partition

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

### summary

How can I use Python to specify partitions in the fetch time partitioning table to fetch?

### What we tried

I have found that the following is possible when inserting in SQL.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables

but I don't know how to describe it in Python.
I am thinking of using "client.load_table_from_dataframe" from google-cloud-bigquery module.
https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe

I found the following document, but when I use the name `_PARTITIONTIME` I get the following error.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-partitioned#bigquery_load_table_partitioned-python

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/aaa/jobs?uploadType=multipart: Invalid field name "_PARTITIONTIME". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, _TABLE_, _FILE_, _ROW_TIMESTAMP, __ROOT__ and _COLIDENTIFIER
```

### execution environment

- python: 3.8.10
- google-cloud-bigquery: 3.2.0
- pandas: 1.4.3
- About Certification

  - If PARTITION is not specified, we consider that there is no problem because data can be inserted.

### table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aaa.bbb.ccc`(
  c1 INTEGER,
  c2 STRING
)
PARTITION BY _PARTITIONDATE;
```

### What I want to do

#### SQL

```sql
INSERT INTO `aaa.bbb.ccc` (c1, c2, _PARTITIONTIME) VALUES (99, "zz", TIMESTAMP("2000-01-02"));
```

#### Python ( Tried and tested code )

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.enums import SqlTypeNames
from google.cloud.bigquery.job import WriteDisposition
from datetime import datetime

client = bigquery.Client(project="aaa")
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("c1", SqlTypeNames.INTEGER),
        bigquery.SchemaField("c2", SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("_PARTITIONTIME", SqlTypeNames.TIMESTAMP),
    ],
    write_disposition=WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        field="_PARTITIONTIME",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
    ),
)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, "a", datetime.strptime("2100-11-12", "%Y-%m-%d")],
        [2, "b", datetime.strptime("2101-12-13", "%Y-%m-%d")],
    ],
    columns=["c1", "c2", "_PARTITIONTIME"],
)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, "aaa.bbb.ccc", job_config=job_config) # error
result = job.result()
```

### multi-post

We also ask the following questions.
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90760

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the naming convention `_PARTITIONTIME` to another name since it is part of case sensitive prefixes. The code below worked:

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.enums import SqlTypeNames
from google.cloud.bigquery.job import WriteDisposition
from datetime import datetime

client = bigquery.Client(project="<your-project>")
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("c1", SqlTypeNames.INTEGER),
        bigquery.SchemaField("c2", SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("_P1", SqlTypeNames.TIMESTAMP),
    ],
    write_disposition=WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        field="_P1",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
    ),
)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, "a", datetime.strptime("2100-11-12", "%Y-%m-%d")],
        [2, "b", datetime.strptime("2101-12-13", "%Y-%m-%d")],
    ],
    columns=["c1", "c2", "_P1"],
)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, "<your-project>.<your-dataset>.ccc", job_config=job_config) # error
result = job.result()
```

Output:

[image]

As for the query you want to insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO `<your-project>.<your-dataset>.ccc` (c1, c2, _P1) VALUES (99, "zz", TIMESTAMP("2000-01-02"));
```

This is not possible as explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516103/inserting-data-into-partitioned-table-using-bigquery-does-not-insert-data) answered by a Googler. Since in the `expiration_ms` field we stated that the expiration is 90 days, **90 days before** the **current day**(the day python script is executed) are **valid** dates, anything before that are not valid. This query will work:

```sql
INSERT INTO `<your-project>.<your-dataset>.ccc` (c1, c2, _P1) VALUES (99, "zz", TIMESTAMP("2022-06-01"));
```

Output:
[image]